# Issue to start coordinator

Tags: arangodb

I have install 3 arangodb servers. But i have always the same listening port 8529 no 8530 for coordinator so i cannot create a cluster.

tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8529            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      13142/arangod

So when i try to create a cluster via the web interface, i have the following error

ERROR bootstrapping DB servers failed: Could not connect to 'tcp://10.0.0.18:8530' 'connect() failed with #111 - Connection refused'

How can i start and/or configure the corrdinator to have a listen on my servers?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

## Dispatcher based clusters

Please note that dispatcher based setups as you asked are intended for evaluation purposes only.

To [start a cluster from the dispatcher webfrontend](https://docs.arangodb.com/2.8/Installing/Cluster.html) you need to configure all nodes to start the arangod daemon in dispatcher mode:

```
[cluster]
disable-dispatcher-kickstarter = no
disable-dispatcher-frontend = no
```

To start a cluster on a single machine you only need to install ArangoDB and reconfigure it once; it will then use the same installation to start the dispatcher and dbserver nodes.

One should know that the initial cluster startup may take a while.

Another side note is that authentication is not supported in this scenario, so you may need to turn it off.

You should now find the log output of the *dbserver* and *coordinator* instances under `/var/log/arangodb/cluster/` so you can get the actual informations of what went wrong.

## Script based cloud install clusters

A better way to get a cluster running in the cloud may be to use one of the scripts we prepared for [Digital Ocean](https://www.arangodb.com/2015/04/digital-ocean-cluster/), [Google Compute Engine](https://www.arangodb.com/2015/04/gce-cluster/), [AWS](https://www.arangodb.com/2015/05/aws-cluster/) or [Azure](https://www.arangodb.com/2015/05/azure-cluster/).

## ArangoDB Clusters based on Mesosphere DCOS

The currently recommended way of running an ArangoDB cluster is to use Mesosphere DCOS, as Max describes [in these slides](http://de.slideshare.net/MaxNeunhffer/deep-dive-on-arangodb) [using some example configurations](https://gist.github.com/neunhoef/4f85f4c64ba27df5492f).

ArangoDB is an official Mesosphere partner and we offer [an official DCOS subcommand](https://github.com/ArangoDB/arangodb-dcos) to manage an ArangoDB Cluster on Mesosphere DCOS.

[Mesosphere](https://mesosphere.com/product/) adds additional services on top of [Mesos](http://mesos.apache.org/) and eases management of the Mesos cluster via the dcos-cli.

If you want to use a raw Apache Mesos Cluster, you can use the [Mesos framework directly](https://github.com/ArangoDB/arangodb-mesos-framework) to schedule the neccessary tasks to create ArangoDB cluster.

Meanwhile there is a [better article about Running ArangoDB on DC/OS](https://dcos.io/docs/1.7/usage/tutorials/arangodb/).